# Introductory Textbook or Material for Discrete Geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, discrete-geometry

I want to receive some recommendations regarding the book of handling Discrete Geometry.

Searched already given search results from the sites, however, there's no reference guide for this topic.

It would be great help for me if you recommend one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9489.html) by Devadoss and O'Rourke is a wonderfully enjoyable book.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Will run to the library tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Beverlie, Chapter 1 is freely available on line at the link above to give you a taste of the book.

Comment: I think one of the authors have a MSE account, [Joseph O'Rourke](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/237/joseph-orourke).

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2509188/118539) posted by @lhf is a very good introductory book at the undergraduate level.

If you're looking for a graduate-level book, you might want to try [Lectures on Discrete Geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-0039-7) by Matoušek. The prerequisites are listed in the preface: "linear algebra, calculus, and a little of combinatorics, graph theory and probability".